# Adding data to an EXIF file

Tags: metadata

What is the easiest way to add data to an EXIF file? For example if I wanted to add a copyright to my images can that be easily added to the EXIF data?

Comment: Related question, with some of the same answers: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/773/how-much-metadata-do-you-add-to-your-photos

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to add exif data is to do so in camera. Not all camera models allow for setting the copyright in body however, so the next best way is during image import. I use lightroom as the hub for my digital workflow, and it allows me to specify any and all exif information I want. You'll want to check with your image import utility and verify it has exif support.

If you'd like to go back and re-add/edit exif data, [GeoSetter](http://www.geosetter.de/) or [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) are two good utilities.

Comment: If you have a recent Nikon camera, like my D5000, you might be able to use this tip from Ken Rockwell: http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/d5000/users-guide/menus-setup.htm#secret

Answer (score 2):

Some cameras, support setting an owner name on the camera, which will end up in the EXIF metadata on the picture.

There are thousands of programs for adding extra keywords and other information, and you'll find people rave about their favourite. Personally, I use [Microsoft Pro Photo Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/prophoto/downloads/default.aspx) which happens to be free, and allows me to add information as to where the photo was taken ("geotagging") as well.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop will allow you to add your copyright information etc to the EXIF, it also allows you to save templates of your common information for easy addition to new images.

Answer (score 0):

Cameras generally automatically add EXIF metadata to pictures, such as the name of the person, location, and other useful camera details.

However, when playing with the Exif data, it's difficult to name one favorite program, since there are many helpful tools available that include additional keywords and information. As a Windows-only product, I could not try Microsoft's ProPhoto tool. Nevertheless, in my case (while using macOS), I use [AnyEXIF](https://anyexif.com/) to alter EXIF data in photos since it offers all-in-one features to edit or remove EXIF, GPS, IPTC, or XMP data.