# What is the best metadata editor?

Tags: metadata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding data to an EXIF file](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/adding-data-to-an-exif-file)

What is the best metadata editor?

Edit: for (OS) Windows 7 Starter, for geolocation I'm thinking to use Picasa. But, what is the best and simple metadata editor? for JPG

Comment: As it currently reads, this question is highly subjective. It would be useful to edit the question to include details of what you're trying to edit; One editor may be specialised for a specific task, such as geocoding; and others may be specific to a single operating system/platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/adding-data-to-an-exif-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For geocoding photos, I've always used [Microsoft Pro Photo Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=184075d2-40b5-4172-88ae-878f81896d4d&displaylang=en) which is free and lets you drag and drop onto a map (or aerial view, if you prefer) - it also allows you to upload a GPX track from a GPS unit, and you can match up against that. It also supports setting other metadata, such as photographer information, keywords, or adjusting dates and times.